# how to merge image and card in bootstrap 5

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

Is there anyway I can merge image and card to be in the same line like [This](https://static.wixstatic.com/media/a77aa0_26c5be51e35641138df91c1e03cc0a3c%7Emv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_640,h_366,al_c,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01,enc_auto/a77aa0_26c5be51e35641138df91c1e03cc0a3c%7Emv2.jpg).

I want the card and image to be merged, but when the user visited the page using mobile devices like android or ios, I want the image to be at the top, and card to be under the image.

I have tried, but the image is not merged with the card:

```html
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://cdn.britannica.com/04/123704-050-023DC490/Pair-leather-shoes.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="fw-bold">{{ product.currency }}: {{ product.price|intcomma }}
                            <p>{{ product.category }}</p>
                        </p>
                        <hr>
                        <h5>Descriptions:</h5>
                        <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
                        <p class=""><span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                            call
                        </span>
                        {{ product.phone_number }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove Bootstrap's default padding from columns. Add Bootstrap classes `pe-md-0` and `ps-md-0`. These two classes will remove padding on desktop but leave it on mobile.

Also, set `height` to `100%` and add `object-fit: contain;` to the image so that it will not be distorted.

See the snippet below.

```css
.img-thumbnail {
  height: 100% !important;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.card {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-6 pe-md-0">
      <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://cdn.britannica.com/04/123704-050-023DC490/Pair-leather-shoes.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col ps-md-0">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="fw-bold">{{ product.currency }}: {{ product.price|intcomma }}
            <p>{{ product.category }}</p>
          </p>
          <hr>
          <h5>Descriptions:</h5>
          <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
          <p class="">
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined">call</span> {{ product.phone_number }}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: But the size of image and the size of card are not the same. I want the image and card to the same in size.

Comment: @Bamagujen_Bahaushe. You're welcome. :) Ahhh... I don't know. I wouldn't downvote it. You provided all the information I needed (except that it was not clear to me that you wanted the image and card to be the same size). Most importantly, you also included a code snippet, so I was able to reproduce the problem. It's StackOverflow. People are different. Although there are clear guidelines on how to ask a "good" question, at the end of the day, we can all read the same guidelines but interpret them a bit differently. Don't take it personally. All the best in the future.

Comment: Thank you Rok Benko. May God bless you.